# Ninject InRequestScope() vs InThreadScope()

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

What the difference between them ? `InRequestScope` relies on `HttpContext.Current` which is available only from request thread, so is it different from `InThreadScope` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a binding `InThreadScope` when you expect your objects to live in the context of the HttpRequest, you will encounter many issues :

- **phantom objects** : a thread will be used to serve many requests. Some objects which were instantiated when the thread started to serve its first request will be reused over and over in the contexts of other requests, where you would expect to have new objects instantiated
- **object leaks** : some objects like SqlConnections which must be disposed at the end of the request will not be disposed anymore until the thread is recycled, which you have no control on
- **random context switches** : async/await operations often mean thread switching. This will lead to unexpected behaviours as factories may return different object before and after the await operation

You should not not use `InThreadScope` in the context of an HttpRequest, as you should not use the `ThreadStatic` attribute in this same context

Comment: so than, how to inject something in really request scope, which will be available across threads, that were run from the request thread? I need to store a session id for current request and use it from any application layer, even though the code run in another thread.

Comment: @user3233682 you need to pass the session id as parameter to your background threads launched by the http request.

Comment: so no another solutions about it? if there are a thousands of methods, is this good? if some service method called from controller and that service method make call to 3rd party httpclient, that is injected in service. where i should pass my session id and should be added to headers when the object is created

Comment: @user3233682 you can for exemple wrap your background tasks actions invocations in another action which sets the ThreadStatic field, or even defines a new custom Ninject scope. I guess you should post a separate question on that matter